# Mocking Next.js getInitialProps in _app

Tags: next.js, cypress, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to find a way to mock `Next.js`'s `getInitialProps`.

I'm currently using cypress to run E2E tests and can't find a way to mock the serverside fetch without spinning up a mock server for the fetch. I was curious if anyone has found a better approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Starting with this page of the NextJs documentation: [NextJs - getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-initial-props)

> Good to know: `getInitialProps` is a **legacy API**. We recommend using `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` instead.

I decided to work with `getServerSideProps` only - hopefully this will translate into your particular SSR method.

---

**A prior example**

Gleb Bahmutov has a blog about this here [Mock Network When Using Next.js getServerSideProps Call](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/mock-network-from-server/) but it's Cypress v9 project and the repo hasn't been updated to Cypress 10+ (which does not bode well).

Anyway, I tried running this repo in Cypress 12.17.0 but the NextJs server kept restarting the Cypress GUI (or vice-versa) so I guess the warning about not starting a server inside the Cypress node process is valid.

---

**Using a NextJs Custom Server**

Ref: [NextJs Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server)

> A custom Next.js server allows you to start a server 100% programmatically in order to use **custom server patterns**.

actually I used the one at [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-js-custom-server/), but I don't think it matters which one you use.

With Gleb's app and spec as a starting point, I added a simple patch to the `global.fetch()` method which is used in the app's `getServerSideProps` call.

The steps are

- create a `mocks.json` file with the mock data you wish to test with
- start the custom server
- navigate to `localhost:3000` to check that app is up
- start `cypress open` and run the spec

**/server/server.js**

Run in terminal with `/node ./server/server.js` or add a `package.json` script.

```js
const next = require('next')
const http = require('http')
const mocks = require('./mocks.json')

const app = next({dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'})

/* Cypress mocking for getServerSideProps */
const originalFetch = global.fetch
global.fetch = (url) => {
  const mock = mocks[url]
  if (mock) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(mock.body), {status: mock.status})
  } else {
    return originalFetch(url)
  }
}

/* "standard" NextJs custom server */
app.prepare().then(() => {
 const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('req.url', req.url)
   // Handle API routes
   if (req.url.startsWith('/api')) {
     // Your API handling logic here
   } else {
     // Handle Next.js routes
     return app.getRequestHandler()(req, res)
   }
 })
 server.listen(3000, (err) => {
   if (err) throw err
   console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
 })
})
```

**/server/mocks.json**

```js
{
  "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/": {  // exact match to URL called in the app
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": {
      "id": "NmbFtH69hFd",
      "joke": "Our wedding was so beautiful, even the cake was in tiers",
      "status": 200
    }
  }
}
```

**/cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js**

```js
const mocks = require('../../server/mocks.json')

it('getServerSideProps returns mock', () => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')

  cy.get('[data-cy="joke"]')
    .should('have.text', mocks['https://icanhazdadjoke.com/'].body.joke)
})
```

**result**

[image]

**Removing the server.js block that implements mocking**

[image]

**Limitations**

You can't set mock data on-the-fly inside the Cypress test, since the server has already run before the test starts.

It may be possible to do so with a `cy.exec()` to start and stop the server, but I didn't try that out.

If restarting the server is possible, then `mocks.json` can be changed from inside the test, but I'm happy to set up the mocks in a static file as it reduces complexity.