# Nock JS mocking tool produces error `Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cypress, nock

I am trying to use this tool called **Nock JS**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock

with a **Next JS**, **React** demo app tested using **Cypress**

• Next JS 13.4

• Cypress 12.17.1

• React 18.2

**e2e/homepage.cy.js**

```
describe('weather app spec', () => {
  it('can load the current weather', () => {


    const nock = require('nock')

    const scope = nock('https://api.openweathermap.org')
      .get('/data/2.5/weather')
      .reply(200, {
      "coord":  {
           "lon": -73.9629,
           "lat": 40.6884
      },
      "weather"  :
        [{"id": 211, "main": "scattered clouds", "description": "scattered clouds", "icon": "11d"}, {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "10d"
      }],
      "base" : "stations",
      "main":
      {
        "temp": 299.25,
        "feels_like": 299.25,
        "temp_min": 296.15,
        "temp_max": 303.46,
        "pressure": 1014,
        "humidity": 75
      }

    })

    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('#__next').should('contain', "Click to get your weather")
    cy.contains('Get Weather').click()

    cy.contains("Current weather is scattered clouds")
  })
})
```

If the test does not have nock, the test passes (expected behavior):

[image]

Of course, I don't want to call the Open weather API every time i run the test, and now the test is hard-coded to "scattered clouds" which will change as the weather changes.

So I want Nock to mock the HTTP response from the external API, fixing it in place for all test runs

However, if I add the line `scope = nock('https://api.openweathermap.org')` (you see above), I get:

```
Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

[image]

Although I don't think it is related to why Nock is giving me this error, for reference, here is implementation code:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_APP_API_KEY

  const query = context.query

  const lat = query.lat
  const long = query.long

  if (lat && long) {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY}`;

    const res = await fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          if (Number(result.cod) === 200) {
            // success result
            const weatherSummary = result.weather[0].description;
            const k_temp = result.main.temp;
            return {forecastSuccess: true,  weatherSummary, temp: k_temp}
          } else {
            return {forecastSuccess: false}
          }
        }
      )
    return {props: res}
  } else {
    return {props: {}}
  }
}


export default function Home({forecastSuccess, weatherSummary, temp}) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [lat, setLat] = useState(undefined);
  const [long, setLong] = useState(undefined);

  const getLocationAndWeather =  () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (location) => {
      setLat(location.coords.latitude)
      setLong(location.coords.longitude)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lat && long) {
      refreshData();
    }
  }, [lat, long])
  const refreshData = () => {
    router.replace(`${router.asPath}?lat=${lat}&long=${long}`);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>Click to get your weather:</p>
      <br />
      <input type={"submit"} onClick={ getLocationAndWeather } data-test-id={'get-weather-button'} value={"Get Weather"}/>

      <h1>
        { forecastSuccess && `Current weather is ${weatherSummary}`}
      </h1>
      <h2>
        { forecastSuccess && `${temp} °F`}
      </h2>
      <br />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NockJS is a Node library, so most likely you can't import it into the test (which runs in the browser) and run it there.

I have a semi-answer here [Mocking Next.js getInitialProps in _app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76645530/18573065) which might suit your need.

Essentially,

- In NextJs SSR makes it near impossible to mock API requests in Cypress because the server performs the request before Cypress is able to open the web page.
- You can fairly easily set up "static" mocks with NextJs custom server, but that only allows one set of mock data.
- In theory you could rig the mock server to start and stop from inside the test using `cy.exec()` and before `cy.visit()` you would set up the mock data to suit that particular test.
- Gleb Bahmutov has an [example](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/mock-network-from-server/) using NockJs from a Cypress task, but it's written in Cypress v9 and I could not get it to upgrade to the latest version. But it's a viable approach if you want to use the older version, and also a good example of using NockJs with Cypress that you may be able to adapt.

---

#### NockJs not compatable with NextJs SSR?

One thing I forgot to mention is that NextJs show the experimental NodeJs `fetch()` in their example (see above link)

```js
import { NextPageContext } from 'next'
 
Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx: NextPageContext) => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
  ...
```

But [Nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) says

> **Warning**
> nock is currently not compatible with **Node's experimental native fetch** implementation.
> See [#2397](https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/2397)

I mention this in case you are following the NextJs example.

You can use **NodeJs http** as an alternative, but that would require you to downgrade your app.

Comment: thank you! the linked blog post is exactly what I need. Thanks for the explanation, new to this area. Will attempt to get it working and revert back here.